# jQuery not found when I try to use the ekko-lightbox with webpack

Tags: jquery, laravel, webpack, lightbox, bootstrap-lightbox

I have a laravel project (webpack/laravel mix), and I would like to use the ekko-lightbox plugin. I installed it with npm, but it doesn't work. I always got the following error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined at
>   Object../node_modules/ekko-lightbox/dist/ekko-lightbox.min.js

Of course I imported the jquery and the ekko-lightbox also, but it doesn't work.
Here is my js:

```
import 'slick-carousel';
import 'ekko-lightbox';
import $ from 'jquery';
window.$ = window.jQuery = $;
```

The slick is working fine, but the ekko-lightbox doesn't want to work.

What I should to do? What do I do wrong?

Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

### Fixing error: `jquery not found` when using `ekko-lightbox` with `Webpack`

The issue is because jquery isnt accessible in the imported `ekko-lighbox`, so

Append the below to your `webpack.config.js`:

```
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: 'jquery',
      jQuery: 'jquery'
    })
  ]
```

And in your JS file, **remove all the jquery related imports** as *webpack automatically loads modules instead of having to import or require them everywhere.*

```js
import 'slick-carousel';
import 'ekko-lightbox';
// removed all jquery related imports
```